# Парсинг данных массивом C++

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, for

В общем вопрос такой. Цикл парсит элементы массива и после каждого элемента ждёт ввода от пользователя
Как сделать так, чтобы он пропарсил сначала весь массив элементов, а потом юзал условный оператор и сравнивал данные?

````
    cin >> typ;
    cout << "Enter the breed of animal" << endl;
    cin >> bred;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        if (typ == animals[i].type && bred == animals[i].breed)
        {
            cout << "Type: " << animals[i].type << endl;
            cout << "Breed: " << animals[i].breed << endl;
            cout << "Country: " << animals[i].country << endl;
            cout << "Color: " << animals[i].color << endl;
            cout << "Date of birth: " << animals[i].den_rozhdeniya << "." << animals[i].month_rozhdeniya << "." << animals[i].year_rozhdeniya << endl;
            cout << "How many years live: " << animals[i].age << " let" << endl;
            cout << "Price: " << animals[i].price << " $" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Manager: " << animals[i].meneger.surname << " " << animals[i].meneger.name << " " << animals[i].meneger.patronymic << endl;
            cout << "Birth year: " << animals[i].meneger.god_rozhdenia << endl;
            cout << "Phone number: " << animals[i].meneger.nomer_telefona << endl;
            cout << "Seniority: " << animals[i].meneger.trudovoy_stazh << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Do you want to buy this animal?" << endl;
            cout << "1-Yes \n2-No" << endl;
            cin >> l;
            if (l == 1)```
````